# Problemas con un regex

Tags: java, regex

Tengo esta ecuación 2x^2+7x-1 la cual por medio de un regex remueve lo que son los siguientes caracteres: **[x],[x^n].** para poder resolverlas por medio de la formula general.
Este es mi siguiente código

```
public void resolver(String msg) throws IOException {
        if(!msg.matches("^(?:([+-]?\\d+|)x\\^[0-9])?(?:([+-]?\\d+)x)?([+-]?\\d+)?$")){
            msg.trim();
            System.out.println("No es una ecuación cuadrática");
            System.exit(1);
        } else {
            //  System.out.println(msg);
        }


        String[] lista = new String[3];
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?:([+-]?[0-9]+?|)x\\^2)?(?:([+-]?\\d+)x)?([+-]?\\d+)?$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(msg);
        while (m.find()){


            lista[0] = m.group(1);
            lista[1] = m.group(2);
            lista[2] = m.group(3);
        }
        if(lista[0].isEmpty()){
            lista[0] = "1";
        }
        String a =  lista[0];
        String b =  lista[1];
        String c =  lista[2];


        Double a1 = Double.valueOf(a);
        Double b1 = Double.valueOf(b);
        Double c1 = Double.valueOf(c);

       System.out.println(a1+" "+b1+""+" "+c1);

     //  Double p1 = ((b1*b1)-(4*(a1*c1)));
       Double p2 = Math.sqrt((b1*b1)-(4*(a1*c1)));
       // System.out.println(p1);

       if(p2 <= 0){
           System.out.println("Raiz Imaginaria. No se puede Resolver");
       } else {

           x1 = (-b1  + p2) / (2*a1);
           x2 = (-b1  - p2) / (2*a1);
           System.out.println("X1 = " + " "+ x1);
           System.out.println("X2 = " + " "+ x2);
           String mensaje2 = "\n"+"X1 = "+x1+"\n"+"X2"+" "+x2;
```

El problema es que cuando alguien mete un signo negativo a la operación por ejemplo -x^2+7x-1, el programa lo toma como si no fuera una expresión regular dado a las validaciónes.

**Edit**:
Perdón, no aparece como tal un error, si no que en la expresión regular no reconoce la ecuación si no hay un numero después del signo "-" y antes de "x^2"

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Sé más específico ¿Qué error te sale?

Comment: Estimado, no puedo reproducir el error. Me obtiene estos datos `-2.0 7.0 -1.0
X1 =  0.14921894064178787
X2 =  3.350781059358212` Tu regex si cubre el negativos.

Comment: @Rcordoval Listo, ya modifique la publicación, dado que me confundi en cierto aspecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es este trozo: `([+-]?\d+|)`

Que quiere decir:

- Un signo + o - opcional
- Al menos un número

-ó-

- Nada

Es decir, que nunca podrías tener `-x` porque la primera posibilidad es la que te permite el signo, pero ahí es obligatorio el número.

Parece un problema de agrupar las opciones. Probablemente querías escribir: `([+-]?(?:\d+|))`. De esta manera, permites siempre el signo y luego tienes las dos opciones (número o nada)

[Demo: `^(?:(\[+-\]?(?:\d+|))x\^\[0-9\])?(?:(\[+-\]?\d+)x)?(\[+-\]?\d+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/Pl5dC1/1/)

Aunque igualmente sigue siendo una manera extraña de escribirlo. En estos casos es más común utilizar el cuantificador `*`, que significa 0 o más veces, así `([+-]?\d*)`

[Demo: `^(?:(\[+-\]?\d*)x\^\[0-9\])?(?:(\[+-\]?\d+)x)?(\[+-\]?\d+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/Pl5dC1/2/)

Comment: Gracias, funcionó de maravilla!